# AppStore doesn't provide an option to not to publish app automatically

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have just uploaded new app to the AppStore using iTunes connect and didn't see a way to not to publish app automatically

Does it mean that for new apps Apple no longer provides way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 5th Sep**

They just rolled out a major UI change to the iTunes Connect website.

The *Version Release* section is now down the bottom of one giant page for each version. This is a good change as it means you can go back and alter this setting whilst your app is still in a *Waiting for Upload* state.

**Prior**
At least as of Sep 2014, the question about automatic pushing is exposed as a final screen after the main form you fill in when you push the Ready to Upload Binary button.

This is unfortunately a one-way process - you can't go back and edit your answers in these screens, for a given version. You have to force it by uploading a version that is rejected then go through the screens again. (I just found out the hard way as a client painstakingly filled in the forms for all NINETY SIX apps then I had to go through uploading them all and repeating the forms - it's been a long day.)

See [Apple's help](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

I think it asks you about that when you create an update for an app.

For the first version of an app just go to Rights & Pricing and set a future release date.